# Adding a column to a data frame that is a conditional sum from another data frame

Tags: python, dataframe

I have 2 data frames, one with data for baseball teams, and the other with team player info.  I need to add a column for team salary to the team data frame that looks up salary data by year and team and returns the sum of the player salaries for that year/team. I've tried many different approaches, but I think I am coming the closest with this one:

```
def get_team_salary(year, team):
    data_slice = salary_data_df[(salary_data_df.yearID == year) & 
                                (salary_data_df.teamID == team)]
    return data_slice['salary'].sum()

#This line of code works correctly without the next function in the code.
#team_data_df['team_salary'] = get_team_salary(2000,'ANA')

def assign_team_salaries(team_data_df):
    year = team_data_df['yearID']
    team = team_data_df['teamID']
    return team_data_df.applymap(get_team_salary(year, team))

team_data_df['team_salary'] = assign_team_salaries(team_data_df)
```

It's the `assign_team_salaries` function call that isn't working. I have tried a lot of different things to fix it and have received a lot of different error messages.  The one you get for this is `"ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"`

Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?  I have tried completely different approaches, like using a `groupby` on the salary data and merging the two data frames first, but I haven't been able to get those to work either. TIA!

`team_data_df` has a large number of columns, but the relevant ones (in order) look like:

```
teamID    yearID
2000      ANA
2000      ARI
...       ...
2016      TOR
2016      WSN
```

`salary_data_df` has relevant columns:

```
teamID   yearID   playerID   salary
2000     ANA      anderga01  3250000
...      ...      ...        ...
2016     WSN      zimmery01  14000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, you can use `.groupby` on `salary_data_df` and then merge these sums onto `team_data_df`.

Take the two following small examples:

```
print(team_data_df)
  teamID  yearID
0      a    2000
1      b    2000
2      c    2000
3      a    2001
4      b    2001
5      c    2001

print(salary_data_df)
   teamID  yearID  playerID  salary
0       a    2000         1     100
1       a    2000         2     200
2       b    2000         4     300
3       b    2000         5     400
4       b    2000         6     500
5       c    2000         7     600
6       a    2001         1     700
7       a    2001         2     800
8       a    2001         3     900
9       b    2001         4    1000
10      b    2001         5    1100
11      c    2001         7    1200
12      c    2001         8    1300
```

Then:

```
sums = (salary_data_df
        .groupby(by=['yearID', 'teamID'])
        .sum()['salary']
        .reset_index())
    # alternative: use parameter `as_index=True` instead of `.reset_index()`

res = team_data_df.merge(sums, on=['yearID', 'teamID'])

print(res)
  teamID  yearID  salary
0      a    2000     300
1      b    2000    1200
2      c    2000     600
3      a    2001    2400
4      b    2001    2100
5      c    2001    2500
```

You may also want to pay attention to the `on` parameter of merge.  They mimic SQL-like merge specifications.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This was similar to another approach I tried, but I think that I may have handled the index part incorrectly before.  Much appreciated!